# Azure webapp unable to access share Azure file share

Tags: azure

The same file share is available from an Azure Windows VM. Despite it is configured correctly under the web app - the access is denied.

The public network access of the storage account is set as "disabled" but it has a Private Endpoint that connects it to our private network (and also the webapp is connected to the same network via a private endpoint)

If I go to the My Storage Account -> Networking and I check "Enable from all networks" it suddenly begins to work and I can see the share created in my web app in /mounts/myshare/..

If I go again to My Storage Account -> Networking and I check "Disabled", the web app can't access it.

It doesn't matter if I made the share (and connection with the website) via Portal UI or if I do it with Terraform using the right access_key.

What should I try next?

Comment: you should use maybe the vnet integration in your webapp

Comment: check this- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/281069/can-i-have-azure-file-storage-with-web-app-service

Answer (score 0):

> Azure webapp unable to access share Azure file share.

To access the `Azure file share` from a web app, your storage account should be configured for public access. If you select the **Basic** and **Access Key** as a mounting option in the web app while adding the `file share`, `service endpoints`, `private endpoints`, and `Azure Key Vault` are not supported.

[image]

If you choose the **Basic** option when adding your storage account to a web app should allow it to be accessible over the public network.

[image]

To securely access the Azure file share from a web app, you may follow the [Mount Azure Storage as a local share in App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=key-vault,portal&pivots=container-windows) for mounting the `Azure File share` in web app.

[image]

[Use Key Vault references as app settings in Azure App Service and Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#grant-your-app-access-to-a-key-vault)

Comment: "your storage account should be configured for public access."  - is there some reference for this? I find it hard to accept that it's impossible for an web app to setup a local share from a storage account that is NOT public.

Comment: Refer this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=key-vault,portal&pivots=container-windows